# Mocking FreeRTOS functions in gTest

Tags: c++, c, mocking, googletest, freertos

For a project, I'm implementing in c++ on an embedded system a component that get sensors-data via a **FreeRTOS queue** and process them into a **FreeRTOS task**.

Because the HW did not arrive yet & quality reasons (TDD), I would like to mock the freeRTOS functionalities and use them to simulate my component behavior.

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so I managed to resolve my issue by combining different answers from the website: [How to use google test for C++ to run through combinations of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213022/how-to-use-google-test-for-c-to-run-through-combinations-of-data) & [Can gmock be used for stubbing C functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989040/can-gmock-be-used-for-stubbing-c-functions).

My answer is a bit big but like that if you want to use it, you can simply use copy & past.

To mock freeRTOS elements, in my test-folder:
**FreeRTOS_mock.hpp**

```
/* Include freeRTOS headers */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "task.h"

/* Include gTest mockup functionality */
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

/* Mock all functions needed from FreeRTOS */
namespace freertos {

class FreeRTOSInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~FreeRTOSInterface() {}

    virtual QueueHandle_t xQueueGenericCreate(const UBaseType_t uxQueueLength, const UBaseType_t uxItemSize, const uint8_t ucQueueType) = 0;
    /* define other freeRTOS elements the same way */
};

class FreeRTOSMock : public FreeRTOSInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~FreeRTOSMock() {}

    MOCK_METHOD3(xQueueGenericCreate, QueueHandle_t(const UBaseType_t uxQueueLength, const UBaseType_t uxItemSize, const uint8_t ucQueueType));
    /* Align with what was defined above */
};

} /* namespace freertos */
```

**FreeRTOS_mock.cpp**

```
#include "FreeRTOS_mock.hpp"

freertos::FreeRTOSMock FreeRTOSMockObj;

QueueHandle_t xQueueGenericCreate(const UBaseType_t uxQueueLength, const UBaseType_t uxItemSize, const uint8_t ucQueueType)
{
    return FreeRTOSMockObj.xQueueGenericCreate(uxQueueLength, uxItemSize, ucQueueType);
}

/* Align with what is in the .hpp */
```

**TestSuiteXXX_unittest.cpp**

```
#include "FreeRTOS_mock.hpp"
extern freertos::FreeRTOSMock FreeRTOSMockObj;
/* Write my TCs by using the FreeRTOS functions*/
```

What is also important is that you must have defined a valid `FreeRTOSConfig.h` and in the **makefile**:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS = \
        -I$(FREERTOS_DIR)/Source/include \
        -I$(FREERTOS_DIR)/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F \
        -I$(PRJ_FREERTOS_CFG) \
        -I$(UNITTEST_INCLUDE_DIR)

SRC_FILES = \
    ./test/FreeRTOS_mock.cpp \
    ./src/XXX.cpp

#Specify all unittest files
UNITTEST_SRC_FILES = \
    ./test/TestSuiteXXX_unittest.cpp
```

To Emulate the sensoric-data:
**TestSuiteXXX_unittest.cpp**

```
#include "FreeRTOS_mock.hpp"

#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <vector>

#include "Algo.hpp"

extern freertos::FreeRTOSMock FreeRTOSMockObj;

/* A sensor measurement */
std::vector<int32_t> input1 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
std::vector<int32_t> output1 { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
/* Not very pretty adaptation function but it does the job */
std::vector<std::tuple<int32_t, int32_t>> genSet(std::vector<int32_t> a, std::vector<int32_t> b)
{
    uint32_t i(0);
    std::vector<std::tuple<int32_t int32_t>> vectorToReturn(a.size());
    for (i = 0 ; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        vectorToReturn[i] = std::make_tuple(a[i], b[i]);
    }
    return vectorToReturn;
}

/** Define the Value-Parameterized Tests class */
class AlgoToTest: public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::tuple<int32_t, int32_t>>
{
public:
    /* SetUp() is run immediately before a test starts. */
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
        algo = new Algo::Algo();
    }

    /* TearDown() is invoked immediately after a test finishes. */
    virtual void TearDown()
    {
        delete algo;
    }
    Algo::Algorithm* algo = NULL;
};

/* The test-case used to loop on */
TEST_P(AlgoToTest, AlgoTestCase1)
{
    int32_t outputValue(0);
    outputValue = algo->run(std::get<0>(GetParam()), std::get<1>(GetParam()));
    ASSERT_EQ(outputValue, std::get<3>(GetParam()));
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(AlgoTestRun1, AlgoToTest, ::testing::ValuesIn(genSet(input1, output1)));
```

If you have improvement propositions, please comment!

Comment: really nice implementation

Answer (score 0):

One option is to build your application for your host machine and then, when your HW arrives, you can just recompile it for that HW.

It is possible to run FreeRTOS on a host PC as the OS on the CPU, however this is not the intention of FreeRTOS so it may be tricky and or lead to some unrealistic hacks when it comes to redeploying on your HW.

There is some support for running FreeRTOS on Windows, but I'm not too sure about Linux.

An alternative is the freeRTOS simulator. The caveat for this is that, in simulation, the FreeRTOS is not the actual kernel (as it would be on your target HW) but rather there are threads set up by the Windows/Linux kernel to run the FreeRTOS code. Seeing that FreeRTOS is intended for hard time constraints this simulation is far from ideal, since the timing is ultimately determined by the host's kernel.

The Windows simulator can be run with Visual Studio (free version), and that port is maintained. there is probably some support for Eclipse too.

Windows simulator page: http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Windows-Simulator-Emulator-for-Visual-Studio-and-Eclipse-MingW.html

Linux simulator page: http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-simulator-for-Linux.html

Comment: Hi, this is actually a good alternative! Nevertheless we have an established infrastructure with (Win + mingw) Jenkins & jobs starting gTest for every _pull request_. I try for the next days to find a clean solution based on gTest **but** I keep your answer in mind if I don't succeed!